# save files in an automatically generated folder in R

Tags: r, directory, save

I created a folder in the local R directory

```
str1 = 'Test_run_'
filename = paste0(sub('\\..*', ' ', str1), format(Sys.time(),'%d_%m%__%H_%M'))

dir.create(filename)
```

how can I save files to this folder (filename)?

Comment: That depends on what you want to save? E.g. `save(my_object, file.path(filename, 'my_file.rds')` would save `my_object` in your folder with the filename `my_file.rds`.

Comment: I have a workbook (excel) so I would like to use ````saveWorkbook(my_object, ....) ````

Comment: Ok so `saveWorkbook(your_workbook, file.path(filename, 'my_file.rds'))`